# Run Code When The Mouse is Clicked VB

Tags: vb.net, mouse

I want certain code to run whenever the mouse is clicked. Most posts I find only execute the code whenever the mouse is clicked inside the form, or inside a certain object. I want the code to run *anywhere* the mouse is clicked. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `GetAsyncKeyState` api and check the mouse left and right buttons. Here's an example that uses a timer to poll

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Short
    End Function

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print("Left button click")
        ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RButton) <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print("Right button click")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```